# Output user first name

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want to get the name of the user to put it on an h1.

What dies this line stand for?

```
@select="option => selected = option">
```

I'm using Buefy for the vue components.

```
<template>
    <section>
        <div class="field">
            <b-switch v-model="keepFirst">
                Keep-first <small>(will always have first option pre-selected)</small>
            </b-switch>
        </div>
        <p class="content"><b>Selected:</b> {{ selected }}</p>
        <b-field label="Find a name">
            <b-autocomplete
                v-model="name"
                placeholder="e.g. Anne"
                :keep-first="keepFirst"
                :data="filteredDataObj"
                field="user.first_name"
                @select="option => selected = option">
            </b-autocomplete>
        </b-field>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
    import data from '@/assets/data_test.json'
    // Data example
    // [{"id":1,"user":{"first_name":"Jesse","last_name":"Simmons"},"date":"2016-10-15 13:43:27","gender":"Male"},
    // {"id":2,"user":{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Jacobs"},"date":"2016-12-15 06:00:53","gender":"Male"},
    // {"id":3,"user":{"first_name":"Tina","last_name":"Gilbert"},"date":"2016-04-26 06:26:28","gender":"Female"},
    // {"id":4,"user":{"first_name":"Clarence","last_name":"Flores"},"date":"2016-04-10 10:28:46","gender":"Male"},
    // {"id":5,"user":{"first_name":"Anne","last_name":"Lee"},"date":"2016-12-06 14:38:38","gender":"Female"}]

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                data,
                keepFirst: false,
                name: '',
                selected: null
            }
        },
        computed: {
            filteredDataObj() {
                return this.data.filter((option) => {
                    return option.user.first_name
                        .toString()
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .indexOf(this.name.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i wanna output the user first name on the {{ Selected }} p tag don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@` is shorthand for `v-on:`, so it's handling a `select` event with a function that receives `option` as a parameter and assigns it to `selected`.

Since `v-model` is bound to `name`, you should be able to do `<h1>{{name}}</h1>` to have the same value show up in an H1.

The `data` section has the main variables for your object. `name` is there. There is also a `computed` (named `filteredDataObj`) that should return an array (length of zero or one) with the matching test data. If you want other fields (like `id`) you would need to look there. Something like

```
{{filteredDataObj.length ? filteredDataObj.id : ''}}
```

would give the id if `name` matched anything in the data set.

Comment: if i wanna output the first name how i will do that on the {{ selected }} ? and thanks.

Comment: use `name` instead of `selected`.

Comment: sorry, for all this question i'm a newbie to vue, if i wanna display the id or another column what should i do? @Roy

Comment: See updated answer. Hopefully that will get you started in figuring out how to understand Vue code.